# Javascript - Get SQL Message

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a PHP chat project and I got an issue when it comes to loading the messages from the SQL. I really have to say my JavaScript knowledge is quite weak, so troubleshoot my problem could be easy if I got time to study it.

When I looked for a script that return my SQL data I found this script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("include/getMessage.php", function(result) {
            $('#main').html(result);
        });
    }, 500);
});
```

The messages appears but the main problem here is that the script has some issues with scroll position, but I came over a better demo code: 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qSx3M/7/)

**To make this question really short:** 

Is it possible to implement the *getMessage.php* file into the demo code I found, so the messages from the SQL appears like the date on the demo code. If so can someone give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use `.append(result)` to make the results stack up in the `#main` div.

You can use the `scrollTop` example from the link you posted.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("include/getMessage.php", function(result) {
            $('#main').append(result);
            $("#main")[0].scrollTop = $("#main")[0].scrollHeight;
        });
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: I tried something like that, but then I got the issue with forcing the user down every time the div refresh. That is why I mention the jsfiddle code cause that is exactly I want the scroll to behave. The only problem is I don't know how to add my getMessage.php to the demo code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't quite explain your situation. But let's try:

On the fiddle you provided, there is this line:

```
$("#smallBox").append(data + "<br />");
```

Where `data` is the parameter being passed to the function. In your case, you would need to pass `result`, that is the response object from your call. So you would have something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("include/getMessage.php", function(result) {
            $('<SELECTOR OF THE ELEMENT THAT WILL RECEIVE THE MESSAGE>').append(result);
        });
    }, 500);
});
```